# How to display a label with small caps font style in Xamarin Forms iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, custom-renderer

My designer for our Xamarin Forms app specified Small Caps for a label field.  There are several discussions on how to do this in Xamarin for Android, but I can't find anything for iOS.

I know I will need a custom renderer and have found a good discussion [here](https://liamnichols.github.io/2016/09/11/using-small-caps-in-uikit.html), but am being challenged in converting the Swift code in that article to C# for Xamarin iOS.

Here's that code:

```
let systemFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24.0, weight: UIFontWeightLight)
let smallCapsDesc = systemFont.fontDescriptor.addingAttributes([
    UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: [
        [
            UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: kUpperCaseType,
            UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: kUpperCaseSmallCapsSelector
        ]
    ]
])
let font = UIFont(descriptor: smallCapsDesc, size: systemFont.pointSize)
```

I know that I will put something into my OnElementChanged method, but the FontDescriptor does not have an addingAttributes method or an Attributes collection, so am challenged in adding additional properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the FontDescriptor does not have an addingAttributes method or an Attributes collection

You are looking for the `UIFont.FontDescriptor.CreateWithAttributes` method.

#### Example:

```
var systemFont = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(24, UIFontWeight.Light);
var attributes = new UIFontAttributes(
    new UIFontFeature(CTFontFeatureUpperCase.Selector.UpperCaseSmallCaps),
    new UIFontFeature(CTFontFeatureLowerCase.Selector.LowerCaseSmallCaps)
);
var smallCapsDesc = systemFont.FontDescriptor.CreateWithAttributes(attributes);
var font = UIFont.FromDescriptor(smallCapsDesc, systemFont.PointSize);
```

Comment: Works fine with SystemFontOfSize.  I tried it with the Custom Font used by the app (Futura LT Medium) and it did not work. I did this by replacing the systemFont = ... with systemFont = Control.Font;.  Not sure why it didn't work, but I'm going with what works!  Thanks!

Comment: @SteveReedSr Not all fonts are enabled with the small cap Open Type attributes and personally I'm not sure about Futura LT Medium (3rd party font?). I would try a different font just to check your code (try https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto as I know it works, `var font = UIFont.FromName(@"Roboto", 20);` and then apply the small cap UIFontAttributes to it) and if that does not display in small caps, post another question...